# Amdatu TokenProvider

Tags: java, osgi, amdatu

Hello been looking at the example of osgi webapp built with Amdatu framwork is available at this [ShowCase](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/showcase/src) even though an implementation performing exactly like the example every time the service instance is always null. 
Also I had read the documentation on the [security module Amdatu](http://www.amdatu.org/components/security.html) but was unable to configure it, does anyone have a walkthrough on how to use the TokenProvider is made?

Thank you

[ShowCase Link](http://amdatu.bitbucket.org/components/web.html)

[Amdatu Security Doc](http://www.amdatu.org/components/security.html)

When execute dm notavail command i gets:

```
[1] agenda.web.filters
  javax.servlet.Filter(pattern=/*.*) unregistered
    org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.TokenProvider service required unavailable
[15] org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.impl
  org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.TokenProvider unregistered
    org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider configuration required available
    org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.TokenStorageProvider service required unavailable
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional (not tracking)
[16] org.amdatu.security.tokenstorage.mongo
  org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.TokenStorageProvider, org.amdatu.security.tokenstorage.mongo.ExpiredTokenPurger unregistered
    org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService service required unavailable
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional (not tracking)
  org.quartz.Job unregistered
    org.amdatu.security.tokenstorage.mongo.ExpiredTokenPurger service required unavailable
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional (not tracking)
```

My Activator is this:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.amdatu.security.tokenprovider.TokenProvider;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.log.LogService;

import agenda.web.filters.teste.AdminLoginResource;
import agenda.web.filters.teste.RedirectFilter;
import agenda.web.filters.teste.SecurityFilter;

public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {

    @Override
    public void init(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager dm)
            throws Exception {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("pattern", "/*.*");
        dm.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(Filter.class.getName(), properties)
                .setImplementation(SecurityFilter.class)
                .add(createServiceDependency().setService(TokenProvider.class).setRequired(true))
                .add(createServiceDependency()
                        .setService(LogService.class)
                        .setRequired(false)));

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager arg1)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Felix Dependency Manager? Could you try "dm notavail" in the shell and post what you see? I'm wondering if the service was registered correctly, e.g. that you installed a TokenStorageProvider as well.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your attention, i append my question with data what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output of DM it seems to be the problem that the MongoDbService is not available. The MongoDbService is created by a Managed Service Factory, so you are probably missing it's configuration. At least a "dbName" should be configured, see more docs here: http://amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I recently bought the book Modular Building Cloud Applications with OSGi of his own and he is helping a lot in my learning about OSGi. I found more information about why I was not able to connect to Mongo using MongoService in chapter 4 explains how to obtain the parameters for the PID works by using Service Manager Factory. 

I would like to highlight the great work done in the book and I hope someday to master this amazing technology.